# Pivoting without numerical aggregation/ a numerical column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, reshape, melt

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
d = {'Name': ['Sally', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'James', 'James', 'James'], 'Sports': ['Tennis', 'Track & field', 'Dance', 'Dance', 'MMA', 'Crosscountry']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

| Name | Sports |
| --- | --- |
| Sally | Tennis |
| Sally | Track & field |
| Sally | Dance |
| James | Dance |
| James | MMA |
| James | Crosscountry |

It seems that pandas' pivot_table only allows reshaping with numerical aggregation, but I want to reshape it to wide format such that the strings are in the "values":

| Name | First_sport | Second_sport | Third_sport |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sally | Tennis | Track & field | Dance |
| James | Dance | MMA | Crosscountry |

Is there a method in pandas that can help me do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```py
print(
    df.groupby("Name")
    .agg(list)["Sports"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns={0: "First", 1: "Second", 2: "Third"})
    .add_suffix("_sport")
    .reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
    Name First_sport   Second_sport   Third_sport
0  James       Dance            MMA  Crosscountry
1  Sally      Tennis  Track & field         Dance
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, either with `.pivot()` if your column / index names are unique, or with `.pivot_table()` by providing an aggregation function that works on strings too, e.g. `'first'`.

```
>>> df['Sport_num'] = 'Sport ' + df.groupby('Name').cumcount().astype(str)
>>> df
    Name         Sports Sport_num
0  Sally         Tennis   Sport 0
1  Sally  Track & field   Sport 1
2  Sally          Dance   Sport 2
3  James          Dance   Sport 0
4  James            MMA   Sport 1
5  James   Crosscountry   Sport 2
>>> df.pivot(index='Name', values='Sports', columns='Sport_num')
Sport_num Sport 0        Sport 1       Sport 2
Name                                          
James       Dance            MMA  Crosscountry
Sally      Tennis  Track & field         Dance
>>> df.pivot_table(index='Name', values='Sports', columns='Sport_num', aggfunc='first')
Sport_num Sport 0        Sport 1       Sport 2
Name                                          
James       Dance            MMA  Crosscountry
Sally      Tennis  Track & field         Dance
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) in conjunction with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
new_df = df.set_index(['Name', df.groupby('Name').cumcount()]).unstack()
```

`new_df`:

```
       Sports                             
            0              1             2
Name                                      
James   Dance            MMA  Crosscountry
Sally  Tennis  Track & field         Dance
```

We can do some additional cleanup by renaming and collapsing the MultiIndex:

```
new_df = (
    df.set_index(['Name', df.groupby('Name').cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .rename(columns={0: "First", 1: "Second", 2: "Third",
                         'Sports': 'Sport'})
)
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.swaplevel().map('_'.join)
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
    Name First_Sport   Second_Sport   Third_Sport
0  James       Dance            MMA  Crosscountry
1  Sally      Tennis  Track & field         Dance
```

---

If wanting a programmatic conversion from ints to ordinal words we can use something like [inflect](https://github.com/jaraco/inflect):

```
import inflect

new_df = df.set_index([
    'Name', df.groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1)
]).unstack()
# Collapse MultiIndex
p = inflect.engine()
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(
    # Convert to Ordinal Word and Column to singular noun
    lambda c: f'{p.number_to_words(p.ordinal(c[1])).capitalize()}_'
              f'{p.singular_noun(c[0])}'
)
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
    Name First_Sport   Second_Sport   Third_Sport
0  James       Dance            MMA  Crosscountry
1  Sally      Tennis  Track & field         Dance
```